# Troubleshoooting a "conditional" sorting line

Tags: excel, vba

Man, this is baffling...

I am building a VBA tool under Excel. Among the many other things it does, it sends emails, based on the contents of a table. But before it sends emails, it households them by email address. It households by first sorting the table by email addresses, and then scrolling up from the bottom, deduplicating adjacent email addresses.

The sort sequence is below (EDIT: added more lines for clarity):

```
' Sort the data by the EMAIL address
  Dim lastrow As Long
  lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Sheets("Email_Tool").Range("A2:D" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Sheets("Email_Tool").Range("a2:a" & lastrow), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Here's the wacky part...

1. When I just run the VBA form straight outta Excel, the sort algorithm does not seem to actually sort the items properly.
2. When I open the Developer panel and then run the form, it seems to sort it properly SOMETIMES, but most often not.
3. When I open the table-which-contains-the-values so that I can SEE its progress, it performs the sort perfectly every time.

The result is basically, that emails don't get householded. The reason for this is because the rows are not sorted.

So...

Either I am misunderstanding something tricky about how sorting happens, or...

...I need to come up with a different way of deduplicating my data (open to suggestions).

Heck, I can't even figure out how to TROUBLESHOOT this deeper than this. A sort command that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work?! When fed exactly the same data in exactly the same order (even from the same buffer)?

Note on image: this is a genericized screenshot of the table -- using only four pieces of data. These SHOULD sort-by-email, but they don't... unless I'm watching the table. (trying to figure out how to upload an image...)

Open to suggestions/ideas, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("a2:a" & lastrow)` is offering no explicit parent worksheet reference. Unless this is on a private worksheet code sheet (accessed with right-click on name tab then View Code) then it's anyone's guess what the active worksheet is.

If this was intended to be performed on a worksheet called *Emails* in the same workbook as the code then reference the parent worksheet explicitly.

Don't sort a single column unless there is no data to the right. Reference all of the data and sort based on the single column as the *key*.

```
sub something()

  dim lastrow as long

  with thisworkbook.worksheets("email")

    with .range("A1").currentregion

      .sort key1:=.cells(1), order1:=xldescending, header:=xlyes
      .removeduplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    end with

  end with

end sub
```

Comment: Holy mackerel! That was not only what I needed, but caught a glitch I hadn't even noticed yet. Thank you!